# Pushing data to object in different component using POST

Tags: wordpress, vuejs2, axios

TL;DR I want to show submitted posts instantly instead of having to refresh my page

Using the Wordpress REST API I am able to create a new post without any issue. The post is being displayed as soon as the page refreshes, so what I want to do is update the `posts` object in my `Hello.vue` file as soon as I create that post so I don't need to refresh to show my newest posts.

I'm not really sure where to start - I've removed all of the experiments I've done so far (importing Post in Create, defining props, pushing to an array, reading about object reactivity on the official Vue documentation, nothing helped).

My `App.js` consists of the `<router>` object which shows Hello.vue and a component called `Create` which displays the `Create.vue` component. This is how my app currently looks like:

[image]
My `App.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <section class="posts">
      <router-view></router-view>
      <create></create>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Create from '@/components/Create.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Create
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import '../src/assets/styles/style.scss'
</style>
```

My `Hello.vue` which displays all the posts:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="posts__Feed">
      <ul class="posts__List">
        <post v-for="item in posts" :item="item" :key="item.id"></post>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var postsUrl = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'
import Post from '@/components/Post.vue'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
  props: ['responseData'],
  components: {
    Post
  },
  data () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  beforeCreate () {
    this.$http.get(postsUrl).then((response) => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

And finally, the `Create.vue` file which creates the post:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <section class="posts__Create">
      <form class="posts__CreateForm" v-on:submit="createPosts">
        <div class="posts__CreateFormWrapper" v-bind:class="{ 'is-Loading': loading }">
          <p>
            <input v-model="formInfo.title" type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Name" :disabled="formSent">
          </p>
          <p>
            <textarea v-model="formInfo.content" name="content" id="content" cols="20" rows="10" maxlength="140" placeholder="Message" :disabled="formSent"></textarea>
          </p>
          <p>
            <button :disabled="formSent">Send</button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var postsUrl = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'

export default {
  name: 'create',
  data () {
    return {
      formInfo: [],
      responseData: [],
      loading: false,
      formSent: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createPosts (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      var info = this.formInfo

      // Check if fields are empty
      if (this.formInfo.title && this.formInfo.content) {
        this.loading = true

        // POST
        this.$http.post(postsUrl, info).then((response) => {
          this.formSent = true
          this.loading = false

          // get body data
          this.responseData = response.data
        })
      }
    } // EOF createPosts
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to push contents of postResult (Create.vue) to posts (Hello.vue).

Comment: you can use [event bus](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) to communicate between components. Create.vue emits event upon task complete, and Hello.vue listens to this event and reacts in some way.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an event bus as suggested by wotex. First, I've createad a file called bus.js with the below code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

Next, import bus.js to both `.vue` layouts using:

```
import { EventBus } from '@/bus.js'
```

Now emit the event as soon as a new post is created (this is sitting in my axios POST request inside the Create.vue file):

```
EventBus.$emit('newPost', this.responseData)
```

And finally, check if the event has happened on the other end (my Hello.vue file):

```
EventBus.$on('newPost', function (postData) {
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!